# Updating integer values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, simulator

I have a dictionary with 3 values associated to each key,

I want to know how to increment the values of noTaken & totalBranch as i pass through the data file, as my current method doesn't change the values, the output of lookup gives me (1,1,0) or (0,1,0) - i need the first two values to increase

```
for line in datafile.readlines():
    items = line.split(' ')
    instruction = items[1]
    if lookup.has_key(instruction):
        if (taken == 1):
            lookup[instruction] = (noTaken + 1, totalBranch + 1, prediction)
        else:
            lookup[instruction] = (noTaken, totalBranch + 1, prediction)
    else:
        if (taken == 1):
            lookup[instruction] = (1, 1, prediction)
        else:
            lookup[instruction] = (0, 1, prediction)
```

(noTaken, prediction & totalBranch are all initialised as 0 above this)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cleaner way to initialize is to use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) , then you can directly refer to elements in dict values e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0])

lookup['a'][0] += 1
lookup['b'][1] += 1
lookup['a'][0] += 1

print lookup
```

output:

```
{'a': [2, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0]}
```

Also note that I am defaulting value to a `list` instead of `tuple` so that we can modify values in place, `tuple` being immutable can't be modified

Comment: Note that OP is using tuples not lists, maybe you can point that out in your answer?

Comment: +1, as `defaultdict` is the solution to all python questions (yes, even that one, hush!)